# intellij idea not removing obsoleted libraries

Tags: intellij-idea

I found out 'conflicting' versions of libraries in external libraries tree. So I checked dependency tree who requests it. Noone. I did `mvn clean install` then reimport project. No change. So I did full repair of caches etc. Not change. Then I manually removed the old library in project settings. Project still builds. So YES, nobody actually requests it, it's not needed. There are lot of these libraries.

this bug was already reported here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010618919-IntelliJ-Idea-not-removing-external-libraries?page=1#community_comment_10390776907154 but contrary to claims it's not fixed.

Can someone suggest workaround how to fix it?
Ultimate version, 2022.1.1

Comment: Is it reproducible with the latest IDE version?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4861945?page=1
yes, but it seems, that we were able to find solution: idea somehow still held old deleted modules, find action made those modules visible again, and deleting them again seems to fix it (so far)